# 親テーブルと子テーブルを利用したSELECT文について

Tags: mysql

[image: 画像1]

**上の画像について**
親テーブルがm_product
子テーブルがt_salesになります。

```
SELECT m_product.product_code,
 m_product.product_name,
 m_product.price,
 SUM(quantity) as total,
 SUM(quantity) * price as result 
FROM m_product,t_sales
WHERE m_product.product_code = t_sales.product_code
GROUP BY m_product.product_code;
```

**実現したいこと**
上のSQL文を使いますと下の画像の様になりますが
塩ラーメンの下に醤油ラーメンも表示させたいです。
親テーブルと子テーブルの中身は変えないでです。
テーブル作成のクリエイト文は変えられます。

**醤油ラーメンの中身**
product_codeに003
product_nameに醤油ラーメン　
他のprice total result に関してはnullか0を表示させたいです。

[image: 画像2]

宜しくお願い致します。

Comment: 以前から少しばかり気になっているのですが、毎回質問を削除しているのは何故なのでしょう？

Answer (score 1):

内部結合では結合できないレコードを表示させる場合は、[左外部結合](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/ja/join.html)などを使用します。

**SQL文**

```
SELECT m_product.product_code,
 m_product.product_name,
 m_product.price,
 SUM(quantity) as total,
 SUM(quantity) * price as result 
FROM m_product left join t_sales on m_product.product_code = t_sales.product_code
GROUP BY m_product.product_code;
```

**結果**

| product_code | product_name | price | total | result |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 001 | 味噌ラーメン | 100 | 10 | 1000 |
| 002 | 塩ラーメン | 1000 | 0 | 0 |
| 003 | 醤油ラーメン | 1000 | (null) | (null) |

**DDL文、insert文**

```
create table m_product(product_code char(3), product_name  varchar(20), price int);
insert into m_product values ('001', '味噌ラーメン', 100); 
insert into m_product values ('002', '塩ラーメン', 1000);
insert into m_product values ('003', '醤油ラーメン', 1000);

create table t_sales(product_code char(3), quantity int);
insert into t_sales values ('001', 10);
insert into t_sales values ('002', 0);
```

テーブルが画像では回答しづらいので、テキスト化した方が回答を得やすいかもしれません。
[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c780a6/2)